# Does Salt Stack support automatic resolution of external dependencies?

Tags: salt-stack

Does Salt Stack have a method for resolving external dependencies which may be pulled from a service similar to Docker's [registry](https://registry.hub.docker.com), Vagrant's [cloud](https://vagrantcloud.com), or possibly directly from GitHub?

For instance, if I find an SLS file or project (or whatever) hosted on GitHub, do I need to clone it and keep it locally if I want to use it, or is there a way for me to tell Salt Stack to automatically go out to GitHub, download the project, and then allow me to reference it?

Is this what the [ext_pillar](http://salt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/configuration/master.html#ext-pillar) is designed to do?

I have been unable to find anything conclusive in the documentation, but admittedly I haven't read everything end to end.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity sake, and for anyone else looking into this function of Salt Stack, Salt Stack **does** appear to support the resolution of external dependencies at the very least from a Git repository.

Salt Stack's documentation on the [gitfs](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/gitfs.html) feature indicates that:

> *Salt can retrieve states and pillars from local and remote Git repositories configured as GitFS remotes.*
>
> -- Salt Stack, 3.4.8 GitFS Backend Walkthru (Aug. 19th 2014)

The documentation goes into the topic in more depth, but basically you need to configure the [fileserver_backend](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/master.html#std:conf_master-fileserver_backend) to support git, e.g.

```
fileserver_backend:
    - roots
    - git
```

And include the remotes, e.g.

```
gitfs_remotes:
  - https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/salt-formula.git
```

Although, at present (i.e. Aug. 19th, 2014), this seems to require a configuration which involves a master node. Apparently in an upcoming release we will be able to support gitfs when running masterless with `--local` ([GH-6660](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/6660)).